# Python: How do I find all functions that return tuples explicitly?

Tags: python, refactoring, pylint, astroid

I would like to find all functions that return an explicit tuple.
E.g.,

```
    ...
    return x, y
```

would be in, but

```
    ...
    return {"x":x, "y":y}
```

would be out, so regexp searching for `return .*,` would return too many false positives.

I suspect that `pylint`/`astroid` might do what I want, but I am open to *all* suggestions.

PS. There are no type annotations - I would rather have something generate them automatically, like in `ocaml`.

Comment: Are you using type annotations?  That makes problems like this quite a bit simpler -- and if you're embarking on a big refactoring project like the tag implies and you don't yet have type annotations, my advice would be to get 100% type annotation coverage *first* because it'll make the refactor infinitely easier.

Comment: You can use the `ast` module to parse the Python source code into a tree, then look for `return` statements where the value is a tuple literal

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Would that work for *return (0,0)* as well as *return 0,0* ?

Comment: @DarkKnight no, but I don't think the OP cares about that distinction.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess it depends on ones understanding of "explicit tuple". Also, how about *return func()* where *func* might itself return a tuple. I suppose that would be an example of an implicit tuple

Comment: @DarkKnight in my mind, both `(0,0)` and `0,0` are explicit tuples.  the exmaple fo returning some expression which evaluates to a tuple (e.g. `return some_var`) would be "implicit"

Comment: As an aside, you are not going to find anywhere near the capacity for type-inference in Python as you do in ocaml. At the end, you are going to need to address it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pylint plugin that does what you want.

```
from astroid import nodes

from pylint.checkers import BaseChecker


class TupleReturnChecker(BaseChecker):
    msgs = {
        "W5100": (
            "Tuple in return %s",
            "tuple-in-return",
            "Raised when a tuple is returned.",
        )
    }

    def visit_return(self, node: nodes.Return) -> None:
        if isinstance(node.value, nodes.Tuple):
            self.add_message("tuple-in-return", args=node.as_string())
```

But you don't need to use astroid/pylint for that simple case, an `ast.NodeVisitor` would looks pretty much the same.

```
import ast

class TupleDetector(ast.NodeVisitor):
   def visit_Return(self, node: ast.Return) -> None:
       if isinstance(node.value, ast.Tuple):
            print(f"{node} is a tuple")

detector = TupleDetector()
with open(code_path) as f:
    detector.visit(ast.parse(f.read()))
```

pylint would be useful if you have something possibly returning a tuple and you need inference.

Comment: ah, `ast.NodeVisitor` is quite useful!

Comment: And it's super well typed like the whole ``ast`` module, that's pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably write something quick-and-dirty using the built-in `ast` module. I'm going to leave the details of actually traversing through the source code out, but the following snippet should demonstrate mostly what you need to know to get there:

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: tree = ast.parse("""
   ...: def foo():
   ...:     print('hi')
   ...:     return x,y
   ...: """)

In [3]:

In [3]: tree.body
Out[3]: [<ast.FunctionDef at 0x10640c310>]

In [4]: func_def = tree.body[0]

In [5]: func_def.body
Out[5]: [<ast.Expr at 0x1064c36d0>, <ast.Return at 0x1064c3e50>]

In [6]: return_stmt = func_def.body[-1]

In [7]: return_stmt
Out[7]: <ast.Return at 0x1064c3e50>

In [8]: return_stmt.value
Out[8]: <ast.Tuple at 0x1064c35e0>
```

What you need to do, then, parse your source code, recurse through the resulting tree looking for function definition nodes. In the body of those nodes, search for a return node, and check `.value` for type `ast.Tuple` (the `ctx` in a `return` will always be `ast.Load` so I don't think you have to worry about that). Note, when you are in a function definition node, you can still find *other function definitions*.